# How can I subscribe or merge new Observable in RXJS and Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I have a service that always returns `Observable<T>`, and I cannot change the code of this service.

Supposed I have a button, whenever the button is clicked, I call the method in the service, and it returns a new Observable. How can I update the new data to UI?

[Source code and playground on StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-1y5i7v)

`app.component.ts`

```ts
import { Component, Injectable, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable, of } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable()
export class Service {
  // Cannot change the code in this class
  public getRandom(): Observable<number> {
    return of(Math.random());
  }
}

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss'],
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(private service: Service) {}

  public random: number = 0;
  public random$: Observable<number> = new Observable<number>();

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.random = 0;
  }

  buttonClick(): void {
    // how can I update the random with this.service.getRandom()?
    console.log('button clicked')
  }
}
```

`app.component.html`

```html
<h1>{{random}}</h1>

<button (click)="buttonClick()">Get new Random number</button>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I highly recommend using the reactive approach:

**HTML**

```html
<ng-container *ngIf="(random$ | async) as theRandomNumber" >
  <h1>{{ theRandomNumber }}</h1>
</ng-container>

<button (click)="buttonClick()">Get new Random number</button>
```

**ts**

```js
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  random$: Observable<number>!; // no need to initialize it

  constructor(private service: Service) {}
  
  ngOnInit(): void {}

  buttonClick(): void {
     this.random$ = this.service.getRandom();
  }
}
```

When you trigger the event `click`, your public class property `random$` will store the `observable` from your service, then, within your template html, using the `async` pipe, you subscribe to `random$`, and it will react for every `click` event, with this, you keep your ts file cleaner and simple

Now, if for some reason, you need to have that random number within your `ts` file, you could `pipe` the `observable` and still keep this reactive approach:

```js
import { tap } from 'rxjs';

export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  random$: Observable<number>!; // no need to initialize it
  private random!: number;

  constructor(private service: Service) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {}

  buttonClick(): void {
     this.random$ = this.service.getRandom()
     .pipe(tap((theNumber) => this.random = theNumber));
  }
}
```

Comment: I need to initialize `random$` or angular will not compile

Answer (score 0):

One easy way is to convert the Observable to a Promise and use await:

```
async buttonClick(): Promise<void> {
    const value = await firstValueFrom(random$);
    console.log('button clicked ' + value);
}
```

If the Observable emits more than once and you want all values, use .subscribe().

Comment: Why would you recommend transforming the `observable` to a `promise`? You shouldn't use `promises` in an Angular project...

Comment: Because they are conceptually _easier_ to understand (they have exactly one value) and 99% of the time _sufficient_ (as HTTP requests yield exactly one value). On top, no need to unsubscribe.

Comment: When it comes to handling `http` requests, you don't unsubscribe from anything, because Angular does that for you, why? because of `HttpClientModule`, now, if you create your own special `observable`, like a `subject`, there it is valid to unsubscribe. Check the answer I gave to this question, I don't unsubscribe, there is no need, and still using `observables`

Comment: I agreed that await, async and promise are easier to understand. However, the project I'm working on uses `rxjs` and Angular. For the sake of consistency, I need to follow along.

Comment: "I don't unsubscribe, there is no need" If that works for you, good. In our project we had many issues with manyfold requests (e.g. the third visit to a certain component would trigger the same backend request 3 times) or subscriptions amassing until the users Laptop was OOM. After all, you don't see if the Observable is auto-unsub or not. And in a code review, it is likely even harder to spot.
Since then, we are using the "ngondestroy->unsubscribe" pattern for each and every subscribe. Leaks have stopped.